# Find a solution for a differential equation, assume that $y(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a solution to the given equation:
$$y'+2y=x^2+4x+7$$and we are told to assume that $y(x)$ is a quadratic function, which follows this general form
$$y=ax^2+bx+c.$$
Now to find the solutions, at first I tried to solve the given for $y$ and then see what I could do from there but, I realized that you can't take the derivative of a function that contains its own derivative.

So then I thought that I had to create my own function that follows the perviously mentioned parameters (the given and the quad. form).
This is were I am stuck, I can not mathematically deduce a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y = ax^2 + bx + c$, then $y' = 2ax + b$. Plug this into your equation:

\begin{align}y' + 2y &= 2ax + b + 2(ax^2 + bx+c) \\
&= 2ax^2 + (2a + 2b)x + b + 2c \\
&\stackrel{!}{=} x^2 + 4x + 7.\end{align}

Two polynomials are equal iff they are equal in all coefficients. You obtain a linear equation system

$$\begin{cases} 2a &= 1 \\ 2a + 2b &= 4 \\ b + 2c &= 7 \end{cases}$$

which you have to solve for $(a, b, c)$ in order to get a particular solution.

Comment: So Im just 100%, you got $a=\frac{1}{2}, b=2, c=\frac{5}{3}$?

Comment: Eric Brown a is correct but not b

Comment: $(a, b, c) = (1/2, 3/2, 11/4)$.

Comment: Ok now I see my mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that $y=ax^2+bx+c$, you can plug this hypothesis in the equation, which then writes

$$(2ax+b)+2(ax^2+bx+c)=x^2+4x+7.$$

For the two members to be equal for all $x$, by regrouping the terms, you must have that $2a=1$, then $2a+2b=4$ and finally $b+2c=7$.

As these equations do have a solution, the hypothesis works.

---

More generally, if your LHS is a linear combination of the derivatives of the unknown, and the RHS is a polynomial, you can try an arbitrary polynomial of the same degree.

---

Also note that the solution that you found is not the only one which is possible. Indeed, you can add any function $y^*$ such that

$${y^*}'+2y^*=0$$

without violating the equation. And $y^*=ce^{-2x}$ where $c$ has any value is such a function.

Comment: is this correct $$a=\frac{1}{2},b=2,c=\frac{5}{3}$$?

Comment: Check $2a=1,2a+2b=4,b+2c=7$.